# Why is findOneAndUpdate() not updaing the document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to using mongoose and I am having trouble updating a document. My code finds the document but does not update the property and ends up deleting the document. What am I doing wrong?

```
router.put("/hostGame/hostConfirm", (req, res, next) => {
    GameModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.body.filter, req.body.update)
    .then( game => {
        console.log(game);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.send(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: can you post your `req.body`?

Comment: the body contains the filter and updated properties. There is no issue with it.

Comment: A common problem is the filter doesn't match any documents.  In order to tell you anything about the command, we'll need to see the filter and the update.  A sample document would also be helpful.

Comment: The filter is {host: string, hostName: string, gameName: string} and the update is {host: string, hostId: string, gameName: string, gameType: string, hostConfirm: number, clientWaiting: boolean}. I replaced the property values with their respective types for this comment but in my actual implementation they are assigned values by a service that deals with the UI. There's no issues with the service or UI.

Comment: `const gameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    host: {type: String, required: true},
    hostId: {type: String, required: true},
    gameName : {type: String, required: true},
    gameType: String,
    hostConfirm: Number,
    clientName: String
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default the original document is returned from [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). You need to enable the `new` option to get the updated document:

```
GameModel.findOneAndUpdate(req.body.filter, req.body.update, {new: true})
```